# How to check whether the variable is empty or not and depending on it insert <br> in <td> and print the value in it?

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty, line-breaks, smarty2

I'm using Smarty 2 in my project.

I've one HTML table in which I'm printing the date received from PHP. For your reference I'm just putting below only the necessary code part from smarty template:

```
<td>{$street1}, {$street2}, {$city}, {$state_code}, {$zip_code}</td>
```

Now in above code I want to check whether the variable `$street2` has some value in it or not. If the variable `$street2` contains some value then I want to add `<br>` after `$street1` and print the value contained in `$street2` on the new line within that same `<td>`.

How should I achieve this in smarty?

Same is the thing with PHP code as follows :

```
$data['user_address'] = $value['street1']."".$value['street2']."".$value['city']."".$value['state_code']."".$value['zip_code'];
```

In above code also I have to check `$value['street2']` and insert a break line and insert the value.

Can someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:

```
<td>{$street1}, {if $street2}<br>{$street2}, {/if}{$city}, {$state_code}, {$zip_code}</td>
```

2:

```
$data['user_address'] = $value['street1'].""
    .($value['street2'] ? "\n".$value['street2']."" : '')
    .$value['city']."".$value['state_code']."".$value['zip_code'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked for me. I've to do the same thing in a PHP assignment statement. For this I've added the code to my exixting question. If you could help me in this regard it would be of great help to me. Thanks. Waiting eagerly for your reply.